# How to solve the problem of unused import on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, import

I'm studying, flutter http request, and have followed the instructions at https://pub.dev/packages/http#-installing-tab- but after I import, this notification appears:

```
{
    "resource": "/C:/appfluter/lat_api_htpp/lib/post_result_model.dart",
    "owner": "dart",
    "code": "unused_import",
    "severity": 2,
    "message": "Unused import: 'package: http / http.dart'. \ nTry removing the import directive.",
    "source": "dart",
    "startLineNumber": 1,
    "startColumn": 8,
    "endLineNumber": 1,
    "endColumn": 32,
    "tags": [1]
}
```

Even though I already installed the plugin, can anyone help?

Comment: you import the package like this `import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;` !

Answer (score 0):

Just add/include this package Name in your Class

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
```